# Access to Comments in Header template in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm trying to access the Comments part from the header template
From the routable title temp

```
@{
    Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentPart.ContentItem;
    string title = Model.Title.ToString();
}
<h1 class="title">@Html.ItemDisplayLink(title, contentItem)</h1>
<h3>Posted by 
    <a href="#">Kevin</a> with ## HOW DO I GET AT THE COMMENT COUNT? ## Comments
</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Model.ContentPart.ContentItem.CommentsPart.Comments.Count
```

should do the trick I think.